# ASP.NET Core Azure Deployment

Tags: asp.net-core

I have taken the giant step to re-(write? Do? Architect, whatever?) an existing production MVC 4 app to Asp.Net Core. We are running on 4.6.2 framework.

The current deployment is to Azure cloud Service (Classic). The deployment has startup tasks (install certs, install 3rd party software, install Microsoft software, ect).

After spending weeks getting the new Asp.Net Core web site up and running, I have come to find out you cannot deploy to Azure Cloud Service (at least not in the visual studio IDE??).  I cannot seem to find out how to deploy to a App Service (even if I wanted too) and install software on startup tasks. (Does startup tasks even exist in App Services).

What are my deployment options? The current production site already has a DNS record pointing to  the deployment and SSL Certs for HTTPS. I need to keep all of these things in place.

Am I out of luck here, or has Microsoft just hidden the answer in plan sight? All of MS samples of deploying Asp.Net Core are simple and trivial "Hello World" apps.

Comment: Have you tried to create publish profile for Azure App Service from Visual Studio?

Comment: If you mean, right click the project and click publish.. Yes. it does succeed, although when viewing the site it does not work. I am sure I could find that issue out though.. The problem is, I need to run setup.exe on several packages AFTER the VM (or whatever) is up.

Comment: please take a look this wiki, it might be helpful https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

Comment: Thanks Mike.. Im not sure exactly how that relates

Answer (score 1):

So it seems what I am trying to do cannot be done. Or at least not done the way I "used" to do it. There is no easy way to deploy an AspNet Core web app to a Cloud Service. And since App Services are not actual VM's that I have control over (no install of 3rd party software) we are stuck. Unless I spin up VM's (and now have to manage them) we must can the AspNet Core web site for now.

It seems as if MS has dropped the ball on this.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a theoretical solution to your problem:

Upload your dependencies using FTP:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp

Create post deployment script to setup external dependencies:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks

Comment: I'm not sure what project KUDU is? I can read about it, however, I find it very hard to believe MS does not support a situation like this. Other then Hello World, how does the "real world" deploy and maintain business web application on Azure? Cloud Services worked well, and we had no issues with this. Why does AspNet Core not support a deployment strategy to Cloud Services?

Comment: Kudu is the official deployment platform used by Azure App Services. It says for git, but you can do it manually.

Comment: Asp.net core is relatively new for Azure it may not support all functionalities.   The best way to fix your problem is to contact their support.

Comment: I contacted support, waiting to hear from them. I would have thought someone had come across this issue before though.